# I want to change ORACLE level#2 to log archiving mode instead of the current mode

Tags: oracle

I want to make that change to the archive log mode to use the redo log files to use it to make replication to database to another server.

This is easy and possible when the server is single not multi-clustered as the current case.
What are the procedures to make that when there are two clustered servers?

I am using Oracle fail safe manager.

I am trying to make streams replication to another server, I have two clustered servers with operating system Windows server 2003. Cluster service is being used. Also, Oracle fail safe manager is used.

Comment: @user2423720 could you better explain your question? which kind of replication do you want to setup?

Comment: is still not clear. What is Oracle level#2 archive? Do you just want to activate archivelog mode in your database?

Comment: Yes, I want to change my Oracle 9i multiclusterd database from non-archiving mode to archiving mode.

Comment: Our application is two clustered servers, one of them is running and the other is hot standby to take ove in case the frist one has failed. What I want is to change ORACLE DATABASE from non-archiving to archiving mode.

Answer (score 0):

In order to activate archivelog mode in Oracle you have to do basically three steps:

1. Clean database shutdown
2. Activate archivelog mode
3. Take a full back

Step 2 is performed in this way:

```
SQL> startup mount
SQL> alter database archivelog
SQL> alter database open
```

When database is opened again you can issue:

```
SQL> archive log list;
Database log mode              Archive Mode
Automatic archival             Enabled
Archive destination            USE_DB_RECOVERY_FILE_DEST
Oldest online log sequence     7
Next log sequence to archive   9
Current log sequence           9
```

You notice that archive destination is set by default to the DB_RECOVERY_FILE_DEST area. You  can change it with command:

```
SQL> alter system set log_archive_dest_1='location=yourpath' scope=both;
```

There is no need to restart the DB for this command. 
More information about archivelog mode and management can be found [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25494/archredo002.htm#ADMIN11332)
Furthermore, you can read [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/backup.112/e10642/rcmquick.htm#BRADV90058) for backup management with archivelog mode.

Comment: I have did the all mentioned above steps, the man problem which I am facing is during shutdown step. As mentioned above I have two servers, one is running and the other is how standby. Also, ORACLE fail safe manager and the two servers are clustered. Database is not accepting shutdown.

Comment: When making shudown commmand from SQLPlus it gives command time out after nearly twenty minutes because when trying to shutdown it on one server, it starts on the other because of the multi clustering of the two servers.

Comment: @user2423720 I think you have too many questions here. Based on you comments in the question I explained you how to put the DB in archivelog mode but you're still too unclear. I will closed your question.

Comment: Why unclear?!!!!! I have two servers clustered together, one of the is running and the other is in standby mode.

Comment: We have oracle database installed with the oracle fail safe manager utility. As you have mentioned, I must shutdown database frist and change from non-Archive to Archive mode. When trying to shutdown the database, if it is shutdown on one server (The running), it starts again due to multiclustring and Oracle fail safe manager. It does not accept shutdown. So, the whole process of changing from non-Archive to Archive fails. I can not shutdown database. How to do this?

Comment: @user2423720 shutdown the DB from clustermanager interface. Then, using sqlplus perform a complete and clean startup/shutdown and then follow the procedure.

Comment: Can you give me an example or snapshot of how to shutdown database from cluster manager interface.

Comment: Open Windows Cluster manager, select oracle instance, right click, shutdown